# Making an image fit to size of the html page using css

Tags: html, css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>TMNT - Rancid Tomatoes</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="movie.css">

<meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
<div class="fit">
<img src="images/rancidbanner.png" alt="Rancid Tomatoes">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

so far i have succeeded with

```
img{
 width: 100%;
}
```

but i want to it make it so only this image fits and not the other ones.

i tried doing it with

img.fit

on my css file, but this just returns it back to normal.

Answer (score 1):

```
.fit img{
  width: 100%;
}
```

should do it for you. The div's class name is fit, not the image's. Therefore img.fit won't work.

If your image had the class .fit then you could just do

```
.fit {
  width: 100%:
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you remove `class="fit"` from `div` and add it to `img` then the effect will be the same for this image as you had for all images before.

Answer (score 0):

You can Go little easier!

Just add `width="100%"` in `<img>` tag.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>TMNT - Rancid Tomatoes</title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
<div class="fit">
<img width="100%" src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR8g4PCYI2ssAVPKlJmC9q4T_k84PE7zOHqAWultSDb-BbSy5YfK-5P0I1f" alt="Rancid Tomatoes" >
</div>
</body>
</html>
```